# Making questions and answer in PHP which can be edited manually

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, fetch

I am trying to make a system that you can create/edit multiple choice questions along with answers. Now what I have is a table for questions and a table for answers, a field in the answers table code:

```
$qexecute = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `type`='1'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($execute);
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
{
    $quest = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute);
    $aexecute = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `qid`='$i'");
    $num = $mysql_num_rows($aexecute);
    $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($aexecute);
    echo $i . '.' . $quest['questiontext'] . '<br />' . $a['answertext'];
}
```

And for some reason it outputs nothing.

Comment: Are you sure your `qid`s are numbered from 0 to n-1?

Comment: First line defines variable $qexecute and the you run mysql_num_rows($execute); Notice the missing 'q' in $execute Maybe a typo but like that it would not work in any case

Comment: People get more and more lazy having SO at hand :-)

Comment: So there's no correlation between questions and answers?

Comment: In addition to the `q` missing in `$execute` that @Pankrates mentioned, you have an extra `$` in front of `mysql_num_rows` on line 7 - `$num = $mysql_num_rows($aexecute)`.